# How to use the same function to more thean one button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

if i had one function and want to use it to more than one button as an example this function:

```
void calculate(button id){
      and here want to test if this button + / - * 
      and perform calculate according to this button 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass id of the specific button, and call fun with argument as oneline call;

```
 void calculate(int operationId) {
      switch(operationId){
        case 0:
          _counter--;
          break;
        default:
          _counter++;
      }
  } 



 FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _incrementCounter(1),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Text('Increment')),


 FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:()=> _incrementCounter(0),
        tooltip: 'decrement',
        child: Text('decrement')),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: declare enum:

```
enum Operation {Plus, Minus, Multiply }
```

then define function that takes this enum as parameter

```
void yourFunction(Operation op){
 switch(op){
  case Operation.Plus:
   //action on plus
  break;
  case Operation.Minus:
   //action on minus
  break;
  case Operation.Multiply:
   //action on multiply
  break;
  default:
   //action on default
  break;
 }
}
```

and use it like

```
onTap: () => yourFunction(Operation.Plus),
onTap: () => yourFunction(Operation.Minus),
onTap: () => yourFunction(Operation.Multiply),
```